# Finding an unnamed union in a struct

Tags: haiku

I have to find an unnamed union in struct _pthread_rwlock in pthread.h in the Haiku open source project. I began this assignment with some knowledge of c++ (past inheritance, polymorphism, and classes), but I find that what I learned do not help at all in my situation. I've opened the header file, and a source file named pthread_rwlock.cpp, and tried to look for the unnamed union, but there seems to be no unions in either file. What would be the correct way to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `pthreads.h`, the structure you are looking for goes by the name of `pthread_rwlock_t`.  If you follow the include files backwards, you'll see the following in `sys/types.h`:

```
typedef struct  _pthread_rwlock    pthread_rwlock_t;
...
struct _pthread_rwlock {
    __haiku_std_uint32     flags;
    __haiku_std_int32      owner;
    union {
        struct {
            __haiku_std_int32    sem;
        } shared;
        struct {
            __haiku_std_int32    lock_sem;
            __haiku_std_int32    lock_count;
            __haiku_std_int32    reader_count;
            __haiku_std_int32    writer_count;
            void*                waiters[2];
        } local;
    } u;
};
```

I'm assuming that the union in here is the one that you are looking for.  As of the version I'm looking at (d06f5808), the union is no longer anonymous.